# Adding to an Excel File using JavaFX

Tags: excel, javafx, scenebuilder

The problem I am having is figuring out how to get data written by the user to append to an Excel File in different cells.

```
File outFile = new File("Stickley_StudentData.xls");
FileOutputStream outFileStream = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
PrintWriter outStream = new PrintWriter(outFileStream);
```

This is the code I have to write it to an Excel File. It does write to the file but the data is all in one cell. Each piece of data needs to be in its own cell. Everything that I run into says I need to make a different class altogether but the instructions I was given doesn't mention doing that. I haven't learned how to use

```
Workbook = new Workbook();
```

either

Comment: To manipulate Excel files, you need some kind of API that understands the file format. The most popular framework for accessing MS office files is [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

As James_D has already pointed out an Excel file is not a simple text file you can just write into. If all you want is just some text like data organized in cells, then the easiest way to get that into Exel is to create a simple .csv file instead and open that directly with Excel.
A .csv file is a plain text file where each line corresponds to a row of cells in Excel and the content of the cells is separate by a comma (',') or some other separator character from each other.